# Как добавить имя файла при его загрузке?

Tags: laravel, storage

При миграции я создал поле с названием документа, в модели также прописал его в заполненных полях. Как я могу ввести свои имена для них в форме при загрузке файлов?

> В самой миграции поле `document_name` определенно как `text`

**Controller @ store**

```php
 if ($request->hasFile('passport'))
        {
            foreach($request->file('passport') as $passport){
                $str_passport = $passport->store('passport', 'public');
                $homes->passportDocuments()->create(['document' => $str_passport]);
            }
        }
```

**Model Passport**

```php
protected $fillable = [
        'document',
        'document_name',
    ];

    public function house()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Houses::class);
    }
```

**View blade**

```html
@extends('templates.main')
@section('title', '| Добавление дома в панель управления')
@section('dashboard')
    <div class="container mx-auto">
        <div class="py-8 px-4">
            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('homes.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">
                    <div>
                        <label for="home_number">Номер дома</label>
                        <input class="w-full" type="text" name="home_number" id="home_number">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="street">Улица</label>
                        <select name="street_id" class="w-full">
                            <option selected>Выбирите улицу из списка</option>
                            @foreach($streets as $street)
                                <option value="{{$street->id}}">{{$street->name}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="">Количество квартир в доме</label>
                        <input class="w-full" type="text" name="kvartir">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="">Количество этажей в доме</label>
                        <input class="w-full" type="text" name="etag">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="">Жилая площадь дома</label>
                        <input class="w-full" type="text" name="s_gil">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="">Нежилая площадь дома</label>
                        <input class="w-full" type="text" name="s_negil">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="">Общая площадь дома</label>
                        <input class="w-full" type="text" name="s_full">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="">Состояние</label>
                        <input class="w-full" type="text" name="sostoyanie">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="year">Год ввода в эксплуатацию</label>
                        <input class="w-full" type="text" name="year" id="year">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="">Изображение дома</label>
                        <input name="image" type="file" id="image" class="w-full">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="py-10 grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-4 gap-4">
                    <div class="dogovor_list">
                        <button class="add_dogovor" type="button">Добавить Договор</button><br><br>
                        <div>
                            <label for="dogovor">Договор</label>
                            <input class="w-full" type="file" name="dogovor[]">
                            {{-- -------------------------------------------- --}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="otchet_list">
                        <button class="add_otchet" type="button">Добавить Отчет</button><br><br>
                        <div>
                            <label for="otchet">Отчет</label>
                            <input class="w-full" type="file" name="otchet[]">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="passport_list">
                        <button class="add_passport" type="button">Добавить паспорт дома</button><br><br>
                        <div>
                            <label for="passport">Паспорт дома</label>
                            <input class="w-full" type="file" name="passport[]">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="protocol_list">
                        <button class="add_protocol" type="button">Добавить протоклы собрания</button><br><br>
                        <div>
                            <label for="protocol">Протоклы собрания</label>
                            <input class="w-full" type="file" name="protocol[]">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="py-2 px-4 rounded shadow bg-green-700 hover:bg-green-600 text-bold text-white"
                    type="submit">Добавить</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection

@push('scriptext')
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".add_dogovor").on('click',function(){
            $(".dogovor_list").append(
              `<div> <label for="dogovor">Договор</label> <input class="w-full" type="file" name="dogovor[]"> </div>`
            );
        });
        $(".add_otchet").on('click',function(){
            $(".otchet_list").append(
                `<div> <label for="otchet">Отчет</label> <input class="w-full" type="file" name="otchet[]"> </div>`
            );
        });
        $(".add_passport").on('click',function(){
            $(".passport_list").append(
                `<div> <label for="passport">Паспорт дома</label> <input class="w-full" type="file" name="passport[]"> </div>`
            );
        });
        $(".add_protocol").on('click',function(){
            $(".protocol_list").append(
                `<div> <label for="protocol">Протоклы собрания</label> <input class="w-full" type="file" name="protocol[]"> </div>`
            );
        });
    });
@endpush
```

Как правильно реализовать заполнение этого поля ?

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте у view само поле для имени, условно, предполагается что это обязательное поле:

```
<div>
    <label for="passport">Паспорт дома</label>
    <input class="w-full" type="text" name="passport_name[]">
    <input class="w-full" type="file" name="passport[]">
</div>
```

Если это не отдельный блок, а часть passport блока (т.е. находится возле input name=passport) то эту же строку добавить надо в js, где событие добавляется на .add_passport

```
$(".add_passport").on('click',function(){
    $(".passport_list").append(
                `<div> <label for="passport">Паспорт дома</label> 
                       <input class="w-full" type="text" name="passport_name[]">
                       <input class="w-full" type="file" name="passport[]"> 
                 </div>`
    );
});
```

И в контроллере, условно, принимаем имя по индексу файла паспорта т.к. они стоят рядом, и подставляем его где нам нужно:

```
foreach($request->file('passport') as $index => $passport){
    // проверяем, есть ли имя с таким же индексом
    // если нет - ставим имя default_filename
    $name = isset($request->passport_name[$index]) ? $request->passport_name[$index] : 'default_filename';

    $str_passport = $passport->storeAs('passport', $name, 'public');

    $homes->passportDocuments()->create([
        'document' => $str_passport,
        'document_name' => $name,
    ]);
}
```

[File Storage # Specifying A File Name](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#specifying-a-file-name)

Comment: Таким образом я просто показываю что при загрузке будет имя файла. А как мне его передать в последующем в свой столбец к файлу, у меня форма не имеет поля имени файла, потому что я не знаю куда его вставлять, и если я правильно понял документацию, то `filename` необходимо поменять в моём случае на `document_name`?.

Comment: То есть, вам надо добавить поле для имени.. У вас код blade это весь? Как оправка происходит? Форма есть (<form>) или вы ajax'ом это делаете?

Comment: Форма имеется (добавил в код).

Comment: Поправил ответ.

Comment: Попробовал добавить таким образом файл, получилось не то что надо. 1. Нет расширения файла которые я загружаю 2. Я задал имя файлу, но в имени использовал пробел, и из-за этого файл переименовался в FileName

Comment: загрузил файл и прописал ему расширение в ручную, все заработало. Но я сразу сталкиваюсь с проблемой, а именно с той что у многих моих карточек будет одинаковое название файлов, и менять его нельзя. Возможно ли как то создавать директорию в папке passport для определенного дома, скажем по полю house_number ?

Comment: Вы можете имя составить с timestamp + расширение => `$name = time() . '.' . $passport->getClientOriginalExtension()` или что угодно вместе времени.. тут уж как придумаете

Comment: Но таким образом я генерирую имя на стороне сервера, и поле `document_name` заполняется этим сгенерированным названием

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122356/discussion-between-indevx-and-yura-lons).